# Buttons or hyperlinks on chart to change settings

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-editor

I've been searching around and don't think this is possible yet but would be nice to have.

Looking for a way to turn visibility on and off for options in a script faster. Currently you have to click through the cog, then on to inputs or style to toggle options. Trying to find a way to do this quickly from the chart. Ideally the indicator values would have an "eyeball" next to them on the status line that would allow for quick toggle.

Is there any way to do this currently? Or would this be on the wish list for future updates?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).